# What percent of numbers are primes?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I understand that there are infinitely many primes and (obviously) infinitely many integers, but is there any way to calculate the total percentage of integers that are primes?
Thanks

Comment: If you ask it this way, the correct answer is $0\%$, but you might be interested in a related question. Therefore, look at the [prime number theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem)

Comment: Also questions 539192, 28540, 804502, and maybe more.

Answer (score 6):

The function $\pi(n)$ tells us the amount of primes lower or equal to $n$. It is known that $\pi(n) \sim \frac{n}{\ln n}$ so the proportion as $n$ grows is about:

$$\frac{n}{\ln n}·\frac{1}{n} = \frac{1}{\ln n}$$

This means that as $n$ grows, the proportion tends to zero.

Comment: Isn't it $\pi(n) \sim \frac{n}{\ln(n)}$? (Prime Number Theorem)

Comment: True, my bad. I'll correct it.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with the circle constant π?